# sed command does not replace all the occurrences of a placeholder in a file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I need to replace all the occurrences of a placeholder in a file. I'm using bash script for it.
I have tried the below command:

```
$Service_Name="ABC"
sed -i "s/_servicename_/$Service_Name/" XYZ.java
```

It only replaces the first word of a placeholder in a line in a file not multiple placeholders in a line.

Example:
If the line in the file is :

```
_servicename_WorkerException(String.format(_servicename_Test.Failed.getMessage()));
```

Now the output looks like this:

```
ABCWorkerException(String.format(_servicename_Test.Failed.getMessage()));
```

I want the below output:

```
ABCWorkerException(String.format(ABCTest.Failed.getMessage()));
```

Can someone help with the missing part?

Appreciate all your help! Thanks in advance!

Comment: use `s/.../.../g`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change

```
sed -i "s/_servicename_/$Service_Name/" XYZ.java
```

in

```
sed -i "s/_servicename_/$Service_Name/g" XYZ.java
```

In other words, you have to add the `g` specifier.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing `g` flag

```
sed -i "s/_servicename_/$Service_Name/g" XYZ.java
```

`g` is used to apply the replacement to *all* matches to the regexp, not just the first.